# VS Code bracket, quote, etc completion

Tags: visual-studio-code

I may be using the wrong search terms but can't find an answer to my question.

In VS Code, as in many editors, if I type a `'`, `"`, `{`,`[`, `(`, etc the editor will automatically complete the leading symbol with a closing symbol.  Great, love it.

I don't love that to continue coding, I have to either:

1. type that symbol anyway, or
2. find and press the right arrow key

I totally appreciate the convenience of the completion feature in tons of other situations and that it's something I may just need to live with, but...

Are there other ways to navigate past the trailing quote (that are hopefully faster/easier)?

EDIT: Changed question for clarity

Comment: Answered at [visual studio code - disable automatic curly brace or bracket insertion in vscode - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46470363/disable-automatic-curly-brace-or-bracket-insertion-in-vscode) and [Visual Studio Code disable auto-quote - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714304/visual-studio-code-disable-auto-quote)

Comment: Apologies that I was not clear enough.  I'm looking for a fast key to move past the trailing thing.  Arrow key is a long stretch of the pinky.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wondering the exact same thing for a while now and was surprised that you can find so little about it.

Finally I came across the extension "TabOut", which solves exactly this problem.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=albert.TabOut